# Can someone explain me this while loop what means?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

```
while (a = b) 
   ;
```

I know that it will probably not be anything so complex but I don't understand what it will become

Comment: It will be an infinite loop unless `b == 0`.

Comment: Most likely a mistake.

Comment: @FiddlingBits so basically it does nothing

Comment: @LuigiSciacca The `;` is required to close the `while` loop body.  Because there isn't a statement (or, it's just an empty statement), nothing will happen.

Comment: @FiddlingBits thank you so much, sorry for bother you

Comment: @FiddlingBits: Or `b` is volatile or `a` or `b` is a preprocessor macro…

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `a` and `b` are variables...

What this says is "Assign the value of `b` to `a`. If this value is non zero, do the inside of the loop (which is "do nothing"). Continue assigning until `a` (post assignment) is zero."

Theoretically, `b` could be changed throughout the program via an interrupt or other source. It could be mapped to an internal register, for example. Note that this is also changing `a`, which could set off a chain of events that makes `b` zero, ending the loop.

If `b` and `a` are not changing/are not volatile, this could serve (in a jankey way) as "clear `a`, assert that `b` is zero." If `b` is non-zero, the program will hang.

Most likely though, it's meant to be `while (a == b);`, which can be treated as "assert that a is not equal to b, and hang otherwise."

Answer (score 0):

If b=0 then it will not an infinite loop. Otherwise, it will be an infinite loop.
Here, the value of b assigned in a. Hope you got it.

Comment: It will execute if `b` is `0` and the effect will be to set `a` to `0`

Answer (score -2):

```
void stringCAT(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    while(*s1 != '\0')
    {
        s1++;
    }

    for(; *s1 = *s2; s1++,s2++)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

The `for` loop includes your answer. The middle of for statement is condition like inside a `while()`. This for loop runs until `*s2= '\0'` and copies data from `s2` to `s1` at the same time. This is valid for the type of char.